# How to grep same strings by comparing two files

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have two files file A and file B

File A contains all the information while file B contains unique information ids. What I want to do is to compare both files and grep the ids information from file A

**file A:**

```
acb:A1S_1863    ncbi-proteinid:ABO12290
acb:A1S_1864    ncbi-proteinid:ABO12291
acb:A1S_1865    ncbi-proteinid:ABO12292
acb:A1S_0105    ncbi-proteinid:ABO10592
acb:A1S_0106    ncbi-proteinid:ABO10593
```

**file B:**

```
A1S_1865
A1S_1774
A1S_1116
A1S_0106
A1S_2677
```

**desired output:**

```
acb:A1S_1865    ncbi-proteinid:ABO12292
acb:A1S_0106    ncbi-proteinid:ABO10593
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With grep:

```
grep -Ff fileB fileA
```

`-f <filename>` tells `grep` to read patterns from file, and `-F` makes it treat the patterns as fixed strings instead of regular expressions. (This is assuming the IDs don't show up in the other column.)

Comment: Is it possible to print line numbers for each match?